# Dealing with OkHttp HTTP/2 REFUSED_STREAM errors

Tags: okhttp, http2

We are Using OkHttp3 (v4.9.1) to establish h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS) connections in a highly concurrent fashion from a Spring Boot application. To do so, we have narrowed down the supported protocols using:

```
builder.protocols(List.of(Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE))
```

Establishing connections usually works fine and HTTP/2 streams are used instead of dedicated connections. However, we observe sporadic error bursts when the server (based on nginx, single node, single address) closes the connection after a certain number of requests has been reached (as instructed by its [keepalive_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests) option). When this happens, OkHttp does not seem to attempt to retry the connection, but instead just throws an exception to the caller:

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:148)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.example.OkHttpAutoConfiguration.lambda$authenticate$3(OkHttpAutoConfiguration.java:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    [...]
```

Requests are initiated like this:

```
httpClient.newCall(buildRequest(uri)).execute()
```

What is the recommended way to deal with these errors?

Is there an option (we may have missed) so OkHttp takes care of this transparently to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this issue you've made the case for us to fix it in OkHttp. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6700

In the interim, you'll want an interceptor that uses a try/catch block, and attempts again in the catch clause if the exception matches this criteria.